# 301 redirect from one domain to another

Tags: redirect, dns, seo

Okay, so I've just redesigned my clients website and updated the sitemap. That means the sitemap structure is not the same. The new site is also hosted on a new server with a new domain name. To keep all the links and SEO intact i'll have to do 301 redirects. However i'm not sure how exactly to pull this off.

**Domain A**
**Server A**

**Domain B**
**Server B**

**Domain A** is the original domain and has to be forwarded to **domain B**, since domain B is the new primary domain. Just a simple forward to prevent duplicate content.

**Domain B**'s content is hosted on *server B*, while the old content of **domain A** was hosted on *server A*.

On which server do I make the 301 redirects in the .htaccess file and how exactly do I pull it off, so that links from **Domain A** properly redirect to **Domain B**?

Is simple redirects enough or do I have to rewrite also? And again on which server do I make these changes?

I'm a bit confused because if I do a simple redirect on the new server b, how can the server recognize urls from the old server/domain? (See example below).

redirect 301 /old/gallery http://www.newdomain.dk/gallery

It doesn't make sense to me that server B could recognize /old/gallery path unless I tell it somehow. But how? :)

Thanks in advanced.
Best regards
Jeppe C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Point both domains to the new server and then use URL rewriting to redirect a request to the old domain to the new one. This only works if your hosting allows you to manage more than one domain, this feature is sometimes called "add-on" domain.
2. You keep both servers and domains separate and you **use URL rewriting on the old server** to redirect incoming requests to the new domain.

Depending on your web server in use you can use different URL rewriting packages, e.g.:

- mod_rewrite for Apache:
  http://webdesign.about.com/od/mod_rewrite/qt/site_redirects.htm URL
- URL Rewriting for IIS: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

To summarize: requests come in to the old server, therefore you have to make the redirection happen there. There are packages which help you rewriting the incoming requests to the new URI.

Comment: Alright, so I'm going with your first option since there's only 1 server.

Right now only domain B points to the server IP while domain A just forwards. I guess both has to point to the exact IP. (Extra question: will that make duplicate content since 2 domains point at the same content?)
So this is my code:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domainb.dk/ [R=301,L]`
So these lines will redirect the old domain to the new one.Then all my 301 redirects will now work, since the old URL paths are recognized and then redirected to the new URL paths. Right?

Comment: Yes, both domains need to point to the same IP. There won't be any duplicate content if you are rewriting the urls. Yes, that seems correct. If you have a question regarding mod_rewrite, please create a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Okay, so i got that covered now. The only thing i'm not 100% sure about is the 301 redirects. If i use the RewriteRule rule as mentioned above, will the simple redirects work? `redirect 301 /old/gallery http://www.newdomain.dk/gallery ` Will they pick up the whole URL www.olddomain.dk/old/gallery and redirect it to www.newdomain.dk/gallery? Sorry if the answer is obvious. I'm an absolut newbie working with .htaccess and redirects, so i wan't to be totally sure before doing anything. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the htaccess file on the OLD domain.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.NEWdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a small service that can redirect your old domain (Domain A) to any destination URL (Domain B) by pointing your domain with a A-record to my IP.
I realize your post is old, but hopefully someone else has use for it. https://www.301redirect.it